# How to pass data from server to android app: REST vs Sockets

Tags: java, android, sockets, rest

I'am writing an android app that needs some data from the server. I am also writing the server side in Java.

- What is the best way to pass data from the server to the android device: with REST or Sockets (like Kryonet)?
- In what format: XML/JSON (for REST) or plain Java objects?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 for REST webservices! :D

Comment: It depends on what kind of data... If it's just a binary file with resources, just download from web or ftp.

Comment: If there are kind of a dialog and things go forth and back, servlet sockets may do... If it's a realtime game, plain old sockets are the solution. But never go with one or another because somebody likes that or there's more porn on that around the internet, ok?

Comment: Yet another interesting question closed. You guys really need to understand that opinion based answers are very valuable. Otherwise we would be turning to Google instead of SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Best" is very subjective, I think a very good way to communicate with a RESTful api is via Square's Retrofit library, which can be found here:
 http://square.github.io/retrofit/

There is also Volley from Google,
http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Agree with nPn, "Best" depends on lot of app and user considerations. That said,

- REST is preferred as it is most widely used and you have access to stable and optimized client libraries. Most of the these libraries support all kinds of use-cases and customizations. Web Sockets are [well suited for real time or live content](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). If you have a different use-case , REST is strongly recommended.
- With Android, JSON is well supported. There is a [core JSON API](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) included with Android that you can use without any client libraries. XML can be helpful if you plan to expose your APIs for public consumption (some platforms eg: JAVA, windows have strong XML legacy).

REST + JSON seems to be most commonly used combination in recent times, and lot of client libraries usually enable this use-case.

Comment: JSON is very space inefficient and REST should be designed to work internally with GSON or Jackson, so as to serialize data flow (buffered reader).a restful update of thousands of items can EASILY shut down because of memory overload (also consider using as async task as opposed to Service so as to not overload main thread "app not responding").  REST will supply a JSON Array of elements and the JSON library will load it all at once even though it will probably consume it in serial fashion later.  GSON will pull every element from your array separately.